# Kendo MVC Grid Multiple Property Column Inline Edit

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Following the example at http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/rowtemplate I enabled inline editing but only the input box for the Title appears.  Is there a way to inline edit both the name and title in the Details column?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: Please refer to the demo on the telerik site.  I do not have an error in the code.  The problem I am having is there is no example on how to edit the two properties in the Details column using inline editing.  I appreciate your help.